# What's the meaning of 'chrome' spoked many times at the video 'A Look Inside Presentation Controllers', WWDC 2014

Tags: ios, google-chrome, controllers, presentation, wwdc

I'm watching WWDC 2014 videos to follow up trends about developing iOS software. However I'm not a native English user, so I couldn't understand the exact meaning of the word '[chrome](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/228)' appears many times at the video '[A Look Inside Presentation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-228/)'. I guess the 'chorme' is not eithor google chrome, chrome os and nor chrome material.

Could anyone explain the exact meaning?

Comment: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/browser-and-gui-chrome/

Comment: @Paulw11: Thank you for the link. I totally understood with the one.